# Drupal upload image (or file) error, tries to upload on wrong server

Tags: drupal

I am running a Drupal site on Drupal 9.50. The site was moved from CentOS server to Ubuntu a while ago. Now there is a problem with uploads of bigger file sizes. It says the client tried to send too large body. The file is a bit over 2MB. I am using nginx and I know, the client_max_body_size should correct the problem. I have set it to 8MB and no, it didn't solve anything.

When debugging the error log I saw that int the error message server: pointed to  dev9.site.com though that's my development server, not the production server ([www.site.com](http://www.site.com)). I didn't find any references to that server name in my Drupal site files (except for allowing it as a trusted site name just in case in settings.php).

It also works just fine when the images/dcs are small the files ending up intact in the correct server.

I have only transferred the database from the production to dev, never other way around.

Any ideas from where to start looking for the cause?

wbr

hank

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand it any more than before, but changing the default client_max_body_size for the nginx server (in nginx.conf) seems to have solved the problem.

Still don't understand why site-specific setting (in server block) didn't solve it.

hank